# How to just call a command and not get its output

Tags: python, subprocess

In Python, what is the shortest and the standard way of calling a command through `subprocess` but not bothering with its output.

I tried `subprocess.call` however it seems to return the output. I am not bothered with that, I just need to run the program silently without the output cluttering up the screen.

If it helps, I am callling `pdflatex` and my intention is just to call it.

Comment: @duffymo: Well English is not my first language and you really don't have to be so pissed about its vs it's.

Comment: Shouldn't you at least check the return value and perhaps `stderr` in case it doesn't work?

Comment: @delnan: I am pretty sure it will work as I am just writing this script for my self. Converting two `tex` files to `pdf`.

Comment: Well, have fun if it doesn't ;) At the very least you'd like to know, right?

Comment: @delnan: Well maybe later possibly, but right now I am trying to understand why `subprocess.call` shows the output and how I can suppress it. Of course I could probably use `subprocess.check_call` but that is another question.

Comment: does pdflatex have a 'silent' command line option.  If so, just pass that in when you use subprocess.call.

Comment: @Endophage: I don't think so, just checked the `man` pages. Also, pdflatex is just one example. I am interested in knowing how to suppress the output...

Comment: What's so hard about ignoring the output? I mean, that's how services work. They offer you functionality and you decide how much of that functionality you take advantage of.

Comment: @David: Just trying to understand how stuff works.

Comment: @Patrick That's how this particular stuff works. You can take it or leave it.

Comment: @Patrick - nobody's pissed, except perhaps you for being corrected.  And you should thank me - better to know, in my opinion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
# do something with out, err, or don't bother altogether.
```

Basically, this "pipes" whatever `cmd` outputs to stdout and stderr to in-memory buffers prepared by `subprocess`. What you do with the content of those buffers are up to you. You can examine them, or don't bother with them altogether. But the side effect of piping to these buffers is that they won't be printed to the terminal's.

*edit*: This also works with the convenience method, `call`. For a demonstration:

```
>>> subprocess.call('ping 127.0.0.1')

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
0
>>> subprocess.call('ping 127.0.0.1', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
0
```

*edit-2*: A note of caution for [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Note: Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the
>   pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may
>   block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe
>   buffer.

Comment: Yeah I can go with this. And this seems to work with subprocess.call also.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` with `subprocess.call()`.  Nobody is reading from the pipe, so this will deadlock as soon as the buffer is full.

Comment: @SvenMarnach So could one flush the buffer right after the call, so that the buffer never becomes full? Perhaps into a useless file that gets deleted right afterwards using `os.remove`? Thought I'm trying to do that and it doesn't seem to really work =/

Comment: @Dana: `subprocess.call()` blocks until the process is finished.  If the buffer becomes full during this time, it will deadlock, and the code immediately after the call will never get executed.  Using `stdout=PIPE` with `subprocess.call()` is wrong.  If your are interested in the output, use `subprocess.check_output()`.  If you want to silence the output, use `with open(os.devnull, "w") as f: subprocess.call("your_subprocess", stdout=f)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach awesome, thanks a bunch! Now I understand what the problem really was :)

Comment: Python 2.7 offers `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: this still pops up a cmd window briefly which is annoying as a background process running every 5 minute or so

Answer (score 61):

In case your process produces significant amounts of output that you don't want to buffer in memory, you should redirect the output to the electronic trash can:

```
subprocess.run(["pdflatex", filename], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

The special value `DEVNULL` indicates that the output is sent to the appropriate null device of your operating system (`/dev/null` on most OSes, `nul` on the other one).

Comment: this really should be the accepted answer. All these other "ah let's not bother with the buffers, they probably won't deadlock your program, it works most of the time" are just simply wrong and good for nothing except causing trouble </rant>

Comment: @phdoerfler Thanks for the ping. It made me aware that this answer is actually out of date, and I updated it to use `subprocess.DEVNULL` introduced in Python 3.3.

Comment: Even better, yes! I was in fact hoping for something like ruby's `File::NULL`, e.g., `system("pdflatex", filename, :out => File::NULL, :err => File::NULL, exception: true)`. `subprocess.DEVNULL` fits the bill! :)

Answer (score 3):

just call it as you are and tack >/dev/null on the end of the comamnd. That will redirect any textual output.

Comment: I don't like this somehow, we'll wait for a better answer :)

Comment: This won't work unless you use `shell=True`, and `shell=True` is evil.  It won't work at all on Windows.

Comment: Don't use windows =D

Answer (score 3):

Use the /dev/null if you are using Unix. If you run any command in Shell and don't want to show its output on terminal.

For example :- ls > /dev/null will not produce any output on terminal.

So just use os,subprocess to execute some thing on shell and just put its o/p into /dev/null.